# How do I run queue on hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have 7 projects working with:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

in localhost everything working great when i open cmd and enter this

```
php artisan queue:work
```

and I uploaded it to my hosting 
but I do not know how to wright cron job to do this

```
php artisan queue:work
```

my app path is `public_html/faker`

I found this code

```
/usr/bin/php /public_html/faker/artisan queue:work
```

but i have this error come to my email

> Cron  php /public_html/faker/artisan queue:work --queue=high,default
>   Status: 404 Not Found
>   Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   No input file specified.

Can anyone right the code to me please?

Comment: Add your full directory to /usr/bin/php /home/ **YourHomeDirectoryName** /public_html/faker/artisan queue:work  in your cron jobs.

Comment: You have to replace `/public_html/faker/artisan` by the absolute path to your web project.